# Supabase select and join a 1-1 relation with Typescript support

Tags: typescript, supabase

I have the following select query:

```
return supabase
    .from("Content")
    .select(`*, Users (userId, firstname)`)
    .eq("Users.userId", "Content.userId")
    .eq("contentId", contentId)
    .limit(1)
    .single();
```

the response object has this structure:

```
{
  contentId: string;
  content: json;
  Users:
    | ({
        userId: string;
      } & {
        firstname: string | null;
      })
    | ({
        userId: string;
      } & {
        firstname: string | null;
      })[]
    | null
    | undefined;
};
```

I know for a fact that Users join will always return a single element, can I avoid the typescript definition to be an element **or** an array? I want it to just be an element (or null, or undefined).

Answer (score 17):

Turns out you can specify the Typescript type in the select statement:

```
type ReturnType = Content["Row"] & {
  User: Users;
};

 return supabase
    .from("Content")
    .select(
      `*,
      User:Users(*)`
    )
    .eq("short_id", shortId)
    .returns<ReturnType>()
    .single();
```

Comment: Google brought me here with `supabase typescript database schema list return arrray` - pretty dumb search request but I did find what I was looking for. I was not aware of the use of `returns` there.